# How to make nhibernate not combine results from inherited objects?

Tags: c#, inheritance, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I have a problem with nhibernate queries.
The result i get back is a mix from two tables.
How do i tell nhibernate not to combine the result from the different tables.

This is my query:

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
   using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
   {
      timeEntryReportIds = session.Query<XXXX>()
                .Where(x => x.SentToServiceLeader == true && x.StartDate < cutoffDate)
                .Select(x => x.Id)
                .ToList();
      transaction.Commit();
   }
}
```

My XXXX class mapping looks like this:

```
public class XXXXMapping : ClassMapping<XXXXEntity>
{
    public XXXXMapping()
    {
        Table("XXXX");
        Property(x => x.X1, c => c.Type<UtcDateTimeType>());
        Property(x => x.X2, c => c.Type<UtcDateTimeType>());
        Property(x => x.X3, c => c.Index("IX_X3"));
        Property(x => x.X4, c => c.Index("IX_X4"));
        Property(x => x.X5);
        Property(x => x.X6);
    }
}
```

And i have another one that looks like this:

```
public class YYYYYMapping : ClassMapping<YYYYYEntity>
...
```

My classes are defined like this:

```
public class XXXXEntity : MwlEntityBase
...
```

and

```
public class YYYYEntity : XXXXEntity
...
```

The problem i have is that when i run my query i get the result from both the XXXX and YYYYY table.
How do i tell nhibernate to not do that!

I did some research before coming here and it told me that i needed to extend the baseclass, but i have no control over the [MwlEntityBase] class. The other classes i have control over.
I tried to change Classmapping inheritance from ClassMapping to UnionSubclassMapping and JoinedSubclassMapping. But it failed when starting us saying something about a missing root element or something like that. I assumed that it was because i cant change the MwlEntityBase class?
Or it could be that i did things wrong.

Anyway, I need help with the correct way to solve this. I can even settle for a incorrect way to solve this, it it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer, don't inherit from XXXX^^
Just create a abstract base class and derive XXXX and YYYY from this base class.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : MwlEntityBase
{
    // The common properties for XXXX and YYYY.
}

public class XXXX : BaseEntity {}

public class YYYY : BaseEntity {}
```